# making the row to be selectable single and multiple select, but it just select the whole row

Tags: flutter

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import '../defaults/defaults.dart';
import 'items/additem.dart';
        
class SearchItem extends StatefulWidget {
    const SearchItem({Key? key}) : super(key: key);       
    @override
    State<SearchItem> createState() => _SearchItemState();
}
class _SearchItemState extends State<SearchItem> {
    List<DataCell> _createCellsForElement(DocumentSnapshot document) 
     {
        Map<String, dynamic> data = document.data()
        as Map<String, dynamic>;
        return <DataCell>[
            DataCell(Text(data['itemid'].toString(),
                style: Defaults.drawerTextBlacknormal)),
            DataCell(Text(data['isbn'].toString(),
                style: Defaults.drawerTextBlacknormal)),
            DataCell(Text(data['itemName'].toString(),
                style: Defaults.drawerTextBlacknormal)),
            DataCell(Text(data['productId'].toString(),
                style: Defaults.drawerTextBlacknormal)),
            DataCell(Text(data['category'].toString(),
                style: Defaults.drawerTextBlacknormal)),
            DataCell(Text(data['costPrice'].toString(),
                style: Defaults.drawerTextBlacknormal)),
            DataCell(Text(data['quantity'].toString(),
                style: Defaults.drawerTextBlacknormal)),
            DataCell(Text(data['sellingPrice'].toString(),
                style: Defaults.drawerTextBlacknormal)),
            DataCell(Text(data['amount'].toString(),
                style: Defaults.drawerTextBlacknormal)),
            DataCell(Text(data['promoEndDt'].toString(),
                style: Defaults.drawerTextBlacknormal)),
            DataCell(IconButton(onPressed: () {},
                icon: const Icon(Icons.delete))),
        ];
    }
```

//<-- creating list of column

```
 final columns = [
        'ID',
        'UPC/EAN/ISBN',
        'ITEM NAME',
        'CATEGORY',
        'SUPPLIER',
        'COST PRICE',
        'QUANTITY',
        'SELLING PRICE',
        'AMOUNT',
        'EXPIRY DATE',
        'DELETE'
    ];
    //<-- creating list of column map it into string type
    List<DataColumn> getcolumns(List<String> columns) => columns
    .map((String column) => DataColumn(
        label: Text(column, style:  Defaults.drawerTextBlacknormal))).toList();
    bool checked = false;
    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Align(
        alignment: Alignment.center,
            child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
            children: [
                Text('Item List',style: Defaults.drawerTextStyleHeadBlack),
```

//Here is the section where am having the problem
// i created the my initial snapshot of the `streambuilder`
//How can i generate an index of the rows that will ease me
//to select single row and also multiple row at a time

```
 Container(
                    margin: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20, 30, 20, 0),
                    child: StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
                    stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
                    .collection('ItemsCollection')
                    .snapshots(),
                    builder: (context, snapshot) {
                        List<DataRow> itemListData = <DataRow>[];
                        if (snapshot.hasError) {
                            return Text('Something went Wrong!');
                        } else if (snapshot.hasData) {
                            var itemsnapshot = snapshot.data!;
                            for (var items in itemsnapshot.docs) {
                                itemListData.add(DataRow(
                                cells: _createCellsForElement(items),
                                selected: checked,
                                onSelectChanged: (bool? isSelected) {
                                    setState(() {
                                        checked = isSelected!;
                                    });
                                }));
                        }
                    } else {
                        return const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
                  }
```

***// wrapping up the DataTable with SingleChildScrollView
-------------------------------------------------------***

```
                  return SingleChildScrollView(
                      scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                      clipBehavior: Clip.hardEdge,
                      child: InteractiveViewer(
                      alignPanAxis: true,
                      child: DataTable(
                      columnSpacing: 20,
                      sortAscending: true,
                      columns: getcolumns(columns),
                      rows: itemListData,
                                     ),
                               ),
                          );
                      },),
                  ),
             ],
        ),
    );
}
```

}

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: even thought i was able to fetch the data  from the firebase but the problem am having here is i cant select  select a single row when i click on the row i get all item selected

Comment: Is it possible to post the entire code? You can strip it down a bit if you want.

Comment: ok i have reviewed the question and posted the full source code

Comment: Single section or multiple section?

Comment: both single and multiple selection. for example if i wanted a single selection i should be able to do that. so a for the multiple selection.... thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Multi Selection

You can use a `Map<int, bool>` to keep the state of selected items by index. Having this state variable as `final checkedItems = <int, bool>{}` it's going to be like the following:

```dart
var index = 0;
for (var items in itemsnapshot.docs) {
  itemListData.add(DataRow(
    cells: _createCellsForElement(items),
    selected: checkedItems[index] ?? false,    // <- Here
    onSelectChanged: (bool? isSelected) {
        setState(() {
            checkedItems[index] = isSelected!; // <- Here
        });
    }));
  index++;
}
```

### Single Selection

Create a variable where you store the selected index. Having it as `int? selectedIndex` the code is going to be like below:

```dart
var index = 0;
for (var items in itemsnapshot.docs) {
  itemListData.add(DataRow(
    cells: _createCellsForElement(items),
    selected: selectedIndex == index,                   // <- Here
    onSelectChanged: (bool? isSelected) {
        setState(() {
            selectedIndex = isSelected == true ? index : null;  // <- Here
        });
    }));
  index++;
}
```

Comment: its still not working

Comment: Does it show some error?

Comment: i really need your assistance thanks

Comment: it shows no error when i clicked on the row it do nothing i try using both single and the multiple suggestion you send

Comment: Please [check this example prototype](https://dartpad.dev/?id=d6c9a4ecba29ddc0b3c381366903f669) I've made with single/multi selection. You can see it works flawlessly. Compare it with what you have and check for errors.

Comment: Hi! i went through it but it still didn't work.

Comment: Hi! good day sir, i used the examples again not that of the prototype.. it did select but also loop back again and create more cells. how can i get rid of that please.

Comment: Would you please open another question and let me know? Multiple questions should be separated into different posts.

Comment: Hello! i have post the question sir the problem is that i have 8 items in my firebase, so when i fetched the items and select a row it loops back a create 8 selected row with 8 rows unselected. how can i solved that

Comment: Checking... BTW, I would be grateful (and the other users too) if you accept this answer here.